# How to pass Complex Type parameters in a service contract

Tags: wcf, service, contract

This is an already existing XML request format corresponding to which I have to implement a web service that will accept this request in this format below.

(Method or operation Name)
(complex type1)
(complex type2)
(complex type3)
(some primitive data type1) xyz (/some primitive data type)
(some primitive data type2) abc (/some primitive data type)
(/complex type3)
(/complex type2)
(/complex type1)
(/Method or operation Name)

I have never written a web service before and had been reading about service contracts and data contracts from past 2 days.

What I know, To create a service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
define Interface MyServiceContract
{
[OperationContract]
declare Method or Operation name(parameters) //How to pass complex types here?
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should define a class whose instance will be passed as a parameter to the OperationContract method and mark this class with the DataContract attribute.  The [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) topic contains the code example.  Does this help?

Comment: Ok got it so all the complex types should be passed as DataContract. So I have to define a class for each complex type and pass its object as parameter. It doesnt matter if there are nested complex types in XML request format and primitive data types are nested within those complex types?

Comment: All complex nested classes should also be marked with the DataContract attribute.  Please take a look at the [wcf service to service communication and data contract](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/7e8fd9fa-370d-4344-9217-4859cc1a7c45) thread...

Comment: Appreciate it.. so we will have object of one class declared in another class just in the same order like we have the nested sequence of complex types and eventually we will pass the object of root class type to the operation contract!